# Wrapper for MessageQ C++ with QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have a small issue regarding one existing MQ interpretation.
The thing is in each part of the program we have to interrogate the message that is being sent/received to which type it belongs, resulting in a massive switch scenario for each component.
Each type of the message has to be processed accordingly (update GUI progress bar, update a specific file, connect specific signals from where the interrogation happens and so on).

What would be the best approach to move it into a single component?

For now it uses Factory method to create each of the needed objects and like I said before the drawback is that you have to ask what type of object was created to implement the needed logic => big switches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a message id, that you process is a switch statement, you can easily send a code chunk to be executed, say, a lambda object. Then, you can merely execute the code chunk in the "slot", without checking and reacting on the message id.

Comment: That's what I wanted to use, right away ... for each implementation of the object, emit a signal with that object and connect it to the needed SLOT => no switch and it's going to be a single component

Comment: You can use a `::std::function` to store a lambda object.